# understand query to generate row number

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I am having a hard time understanding how the following query generates row numbers sequentially.

```
select id, value, (select count(*) from tbl b  where a.id >= b.id) as cnt
from tbl a
```

My goal is essentially to generate column cnt but I'm unable to wrap my head around what is the count function and where clause is doing.

Table **tbl**.

```
id value cnt
1  yes   1
3  yes   2
4  yes   3
6  yes   4
9  yes   5
```

Any leads are also welcome. Thanks!
link to the code [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d0a2d/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every row of the table this query:

```
select count(*) from tbl b  where a.id >= b.id
```

counts the number of `id`s less than or equal to the current `id`.
So for `id = 1` there is only 1 `id` less than or equal to `1`, so the result is `1`.
For `id = 3` there are 2 `id`s less than or equal to `3`: the `id`s `1` and `3`, so the result is `2`, etc.

Note that if this is not homework, then you can get the same results with COUNT(*) window function:

```
select id, value, count(*) over (order by id) as cnt
from tbl
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3d32fe7eb7f740a394343cc35a954598).

Answer (score 2):

This is a *Scalar Correlated Subquery*, logically it's executed for each row.

For `id 1` there's only one row `select * where id <= 1` = 1

For `id 3` --> `select * where id <= 3` = 1,3

For `id 4` --> `select * where id <= 4` = 1,3,4

For `id 6` --> `select * where id <= 6` = 1,3,4,6

For `id 9` --> `select * where id <= 9` = 1,3,4,6,9

Answer (score 0):

If you want row numbers, use `row_number()`:

```
select id, value, row_number() over (order by id desc) as cnt
from tbl t;
```